# Traer datos de una tabla en entity framework con el nombre tipo string

Tags: c#, linq, wpf, entity-framework-6, vs

**Función original**

`var info = Dbentity.Set<tabla>();`

**Intento hacer esto.**

```
String _tabla = “tabla”;

var type = Dbentity.GetType.Property(_tabla).GetType();

var info = Dbentity.Set<type>().ToList();
```

Necesito hacer esto de forma dinámica, quiero una función que con simplemente pasarle el nombre de la tabla pueda traer la información que contiene esa tabla

Comment: La etiqueta esta mal, esto no tiene nada que ver con [c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

Comment: Para que quieres hacer eso? quizás lo que necesites sea menos complicado